# html image position forcing window width too wide

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

I'm trying to make a website with a header that repeats along the entire page width, with the website's name centered in the header, and a logo slightly offset from the website name. If the screen width is too small to display the entirety of the logo, I just want it to cut off the logo to the right, otherwise the entire logo will be displayed (i.e. the monitor/window is big enough. What I don't want is to float the image to the right. I want it to, more or less, be absolutely positioned near the title.

However, I can't figure out a way to do this. I can't use overflow-x or overflow-y (because of browser support) and the mark-up i currently have just widens the window with a scroll bar to accomodate the entire image (see screenshot).

Here is the screen shot

[image]
http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/3188/screenshot03062011.jpg

Here is the mark up and CSS:

```
    <div id="header-wrap">
     <div id="header">
      <img src="title-card.png" />
      <img id="this-chick-logo" src="this-chick-logo.png" />
     </div>
    </div>

--

   body
   {
    background: #dfb1e4;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
   }

   #header-wrap
   {
    background: url('header-bg.png') repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 291px;
   }

   #header
   {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #header img
    { 
    margin-top: 105px;
    }


   #header img#this-chick-logo
   {
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-left: 680px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `"I can't use overflow-x or overflow-y (because of browser support)"` - could you expand on that?

Comment: overflow is supported by all browsers. IE6 has some issues with overflow: visible, but that's it. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 4):

Add

`overflow: hidden;` to `#header-wrap`

Dont put it on the image.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` either needs to be added to `#header-wrap` and possible removed from the `img#this-check-logo`. Also if the girl likes to push off to the right and some of it gets cut off in the overflow and you don't want that I'd move her a few pixels at a time back towards the left until you get it a way you like it. If you don't mind a little cut off just leave it and only add the `overflow: hidden`.